# If you lose rep below a privilege does your actions in those areas "undo"?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Random *hypothetical* question...

Let's say you have a new user (1 rep) who:

- asks a question that gets an upvote (+5)
- answers a "give me the code" question and gets an upvote on that answer (+10)

The user now has +16 rep and can upvote herself...

- she upvotes a good answer

Now the "give me the code" question is stupid and obviously going to be closed. Let's say it is. It's my understanding that this user will lose those 10 rep points and will lose any privilege that came with them.

But will the upvote she has *already made* also be removed? Will it be as if she is a deleted user or will the system not worry about it?

This would theoretically also apply to any other privilege like commenting or other higher rep privileges.

I'm guessing the system will ignore it (easier - especially if applicable to other privileges), but I can't find an the answer.

Comment: AFAIK nothing on SO is ever undone; with the exception of rep recalculation (e.g. serial up/downvoting, deleted users/questions) or mod interactions. So, any upvotes should not be undone when the rep for upvoting is lost.

Comment: @DonaldDuck -  I'll make sure to brush up on my psychic skills so I'll know not to post a question someone else will ask, nearly a year later, from the other point of view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now the "give me the code" question is stupid and obviously going to be closed. Let's say it is. It's my understanding that this user will loose those 10 rep points and will loose any privilege that came with them.

No rep is lost for anyone when a question is closed.  This is not true.  It's only true if the question is *deleted*.

---

But, assuming the user loses reputation through some other mechanism:

> But will the upvote she has already made also be removed?

No.  It will be unaffected; the user simply won't be able to cast any more upvotes until they again have 15 reputation.